# ajax split panel examples

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Can anyone suggest a good tutorial or framework for ajax/php split panels. The idea is to create 2 panels and in panel 1 have a menu which when clicked opens content in panel 2. I have spent ages trying to find examples on google, but no luck. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:
You have two `<div>`'s with id's div1 and div2.

div1 contains a menu with `<li>`-objects. The first one has the id menu1

```
$("#menu1").click(function() {
    $.get('your/path_to_php.php', function(data) {
        $("#div2").html(data);
    });
});
```

This is, ofc, if the path_to_php.php-file returns html sctructured data.

Answer (score 0):

If you use javascript it is quite straight forward.

1. Create 2 panels using standard html
2. Add menus to panel 1.
3. Set onclick events on menu item and load content using ajax in panel 2 using javascript.
   eg (jquery, $('#divid').html(newcontent) etc).

   ```
   $('#panel1').click(function(){
   $('#panel2').text('new content!');
   });​
   ```

   http://jsfiddle.net/harendra/JQY9S/

Comment: There is no AJAX at all here, just plain text injecting.

Comment: Thanks for that. 1 question. How would i layout a vertical panel as opposed to horizontal.